# Image not appearing in Header block

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

This is my first foray into developing an updated website for my bowls club using Bootstrap 3. I have the following HTML defining my header.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <img src="~\Content\Graphics\ClubBadge_DarkBlue.png" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8">
            <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse pull-right">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li role="presentation">@Html.ActionLink("About Us", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li role="presentation">@Html.ActionLink("Contact Us", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                    <li role="presentation">@Html.ActionLink("Privacy Policy", "Privacy", "Home")</li>
                    <li role="presentation">@Html.ActionLink("Useful Links", "Links", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2" style="background-color:#cccccc">
            @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The nav bar is appearing right-justified in the middle 8 columns, the login panel is appearing in the right hand 2 columns, but the image is not appearing in the left hand 2 columns. All I get is a small circle with a diagonal in it - a placeholder I assume. If I hover the cursor over the src=, I see the image I want to display, so the directory reference is correct.

What have I forgotten to do in order to display the image?

Comment: ``img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Graphics/ClubBadge_DarkBlue.png")"``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that "~\Content\Graphics\ClubBadge_DarkBlue.png" is a valid path, but i might be wrong. First of all, try using the other separators:

~/Content/Graphics/ClubBadge_DarkBlue.png

Second, are you sure that the "~" is correct in your path? another thing to try would be removing it.

And, if nothing works, check the developers console (f12 in chrome EG) and check your network tab in order to see what error is throwing the request of that resource.

Comment: I have changed the \ to a / and it now displays. How stupid can one get? I write normally directory paths without thinking about them. It was the fact that the image was displayed when I put the cursor on the path that threw me. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: I meant to say that the tilde ~ takes you up to the top level directory which you can then work your way down to the one you want. I find it easier that way to using the ../ for each level you want to go up from the current level.